# How to undo changes made by animate()?

Tags: android, animation

Can one undo the changes he made on View properties using `animate()` on it?

In particular, how to undo changes made using `animate().yBy(x)`?

Note that I tried using `animate().yBy(-x)` and it works most of the times, but there are times that for some reason `animate().yBy(x)` seem not to be completed correctly (especially when the fragment pauses and then resumed) so `animate().yBy(-x)` is over-moving the view.

I'm looking for a way to make the View reset its properties to the way they were before I changed them using `animate()`.

Comment: Instead of `view.animate().yBy(-x)`, try `view.animate().yBy(-1.0f*view.getTranslationY())`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Although this isnt answering the question in general, This seem to be in the right direction for what i need, please post an answer so i can mark it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xBy()` and `yBy()` animations affect the `translationX` and `translationY` properties. You can get the current values of those properties via `getTranslationX()` and `getTranslationY()`. So, to undo the previous animations, multiply the current property values by `-1` and animate those. Or if you are seeking a "smash cut" jump (no animation), just call `setTranslationX(0)` or `setTranslationY(0)`.

Comment: So whats the diffrence between translationYBy() and yBy()?

Comment: @OfekRon: That is a great question, one that I don't have an answer for.

Answer (score 0):

By using interpolator we can inverse the animation:

```
public class InverAnim implements Interpolator {
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float paramFloat) {
        return Math.abs(paramFloat -1f);
    }
}
```

On your animation you can set, new interpolator:

```
myAnimation.setInterpolator(new InverAnim());
```